# What are difference between the following 2 nginx location blocks

Tags: nginx

Can anyone give an example of Url when the following two configs behave differently?

e.g.

```
location ~ /\. { 
..

location ~ (^|/)\. { 
..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(^|/)\.` is pointless overcomplicated and fully equivalent to `/\.` since all URI paths in nginx begin with `/`.

Comment: What if user request `GET foo` instead of `GET /foo`? Will nginx also append a `/`?

Comment: Nginx will return the `400 Bad Request` error, just like any other HTTP server to respect RFC.